# Initialization of custom plugin in javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, initialization, prototype

I would like to make my own slider in javascript. For now I have this code, that takes all the `.slider` elements and performs some action for each element:

```
var elements = $('.slider');

$(elements).each(function(index) {

    var value = $(this).width();

    alert(value);

    $(this).click(function() {
        value = value + 10;
        alert(value);
    });

});
```

I expected this not to work (becouse value of `value` variable of second element will replace value of `value` variable of first element), but for my big surprise it works - every element keeps his own `value` variable.

Now I'd like to initialize my sliders in a "classic" way, like: `$('.slider').slider();`

I have read some very basic stuff about object methods and prototypes from here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp, but I'm not sure how to add the `slider()` method to the `$('.slider')` objects.

How could I achieve the same result as my code do with the `$('.slider').slider();` initialisation?

Comment: is this a jquery plugin you are trying to make? if yes this link explains the basics. https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did not realised this is not a direct javascript functionality but jQuery functionality.